# Display post from a date range from custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I currently have a custom post type that has two major custom fields that are need for the query.

The 'score_time' field stores time of a score. Example: 12:20
The 'score_date' stores the date the game took place. Example: 01/22/2016

I need query to display post from a specified date range and they are ordered by the 'score_time' field value

Right now I don't have the date range working, but here is the code i have right now.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'score_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_key'       => 'score_time',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
);
```

Comment: to select post by date range, you can store the date with a timestamp format and then you can make a query with ">" and "<"

Comment: i did not understand your instruction. can you please put up an example code? sorry, i am new in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic parameter ist described at [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) under: **Custom Field Parameters**

You need to add a `meta_query` array to your `$args` where you define your range.

In your case the code could look like this:

```
$range = array(
    '2015-05-01',
    '2015-05-31',
);
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'score_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_key'       => 'score_time',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'score_date',
            'value'   => $range,
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'date',
        )
    ),
);
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that your date and time values are valid SQL date/time values. Your provided format MM/DD/YYYY is bad for sorting and querying. Better: YYYY-MM-DD.